# Python loop through nested dictionary or dictionaries in a list

Tags: python-2.7, list, loops, dictionary

I have some data I need to process. It looks like a dictionary within a dictionary within a dictionary, all of which are being stored in a list! This is parsed JSON data so I have no control over the format of it.

Here is some of the data, I've deleted a lot of it as it's irrelevant and for brevity:

```
devices = [
    {
        'server.device.base.phyname': 'IEEE802.11', 
        'dot11.device': {
            'dot11.device.associated_client_map': {
              '68:96:1E:96:96:B5': '4202770DF206F63E_B5F4CE1EAB680000', 
              '60:30:CE:91:4A:96': '4202770DF206F63E_8D4A91D430600000', 
              '4C:32:75:66:96:10': '4202770DF206F63E_105F6675324C0000', 
              '50:6A:03:3E:0E:17': '4202770DF206F63E_170E3E036A500000', 
              '7C:C3:CE:A4:EC:86': '4202770DF206F63E_86ECA4A1C37C0000', 
              '2C:BE:08:F0:D5:A0': '4202770DF206F63E_A0D5F008BE2C0000', 
              '96:E7:96:76:9A:C7': '4202770DF206F63E_C79A762CE7700000', 
              '96:CE:75:57:E2:5A': '4202770DF206F63E_5AE2577510000000', 
              '34:68:95:96:3C:96': '4202770DF206F63E_C43C6A9568340000', 
              '6C:96:96:9D:CE:57': '4202770DF206F63E_57109DCF966C0000', 
              'CE:61:96:CE:B4:69': '4202770DF206F63E_69B4D2AE61900000', 
              '04:CE:CE:1C:CE:8C': '4202770DF206F63E_8CAF1CCE0C040000', 
              '2C:F0:CE:DC:D6:39': '4202770DF206F63E_39D6DCEEF02C0000'
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I need to be able to extract the MAC addresses that are stored within the 'dot11.device' pair. I'm so far able to loop through the parent list and display all of the data:

```
for d in devices:
    print d['dot11.device']['dot11.device.associated_client_map']
```

however this prints the whole nested dict.

What I'd really like to do is return a new list of just the MAC addresses (are they dictionary keys? I'm not sure).

I'm working with Python2 and any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are indeed keys, and so the answer is quite simple:

```
for d in devices:
    print d['dot11.device']['dot11.device.associated_client_map'].keys()
```

Comment: Well I can't help but feel a little silly. Thank you.